# How save WebView when screen orientation was changed

Tags: android, android-webview

In my application I use only WebView for loading index.html where running all app logic(html's and javascript).

Where screen orientation changed, all data from JavaScript variables disappear.

How I can save all data when orientation changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to catch orientation changes and handle them by yourself, because by default the Activity gets recreated (and your WebView will be reloaded).

Add the [`android:configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) attribute to your Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity ... android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
```

And override the `onConfigurationChanged` method in your Activity class.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Also have a look here: [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Comment: This method don help. In onCreate() I call loadWebPage() method where I load index.html. If I call them from onConfigurationChanged() I back to index.html

Comment: You don't need to call anything in `onConfigurationChanged`. Just copy&paste the code from above without modifications.

Comment: @Floern why your code doesn't preserve webivew data if we populate the webview using android get request and then rotate the screen?